# JQuery fadeIn/Out — Prevent two elements visible at once if second trigger occurs during animation duration

Tags: jquery

I have a series of elements containing text that are hidden by default. Each element needs to become visible when its associated button is clicked and all siblings need to be hidden.

This is working but I ran into an issue that I can't work out.

If a second button is clicked while the `fadeIn()` animation of the first element is still in progress both divs containing text will briefly be visible. I increased the `fadeIn()` duration to more easily reproduce.

I tried to fix this by stopping all animations on the clicked-element's siblings but that doesn't seem to work.

How can I fix this? Thank you!

```js
$("#buttons a").on('click', function() {
  var div = '#' + $(this).attr('data-div');
  $(div).siblings().stop().fadeOut().promise().done(function() {
   $(div).addClass('active').fadeIn(800);
  })
});
```

```css
#my-component {
margin-top: 2em;
}

#my-component div {
display: none;
}

#buttons a {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 .25em;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="buttons">
  <a data-div="one">Show One</a>
  <a data-div="two">Show Two</a>
  <a data-div="three">Show Three</a>
  <a data-div="four">Show Four</a>
  <a data-div="five">Show Five</a>
</div>


<div id="my-component">
  <div id="one">Div one</div>
  <div id="two">Div two</div>
  <div id="three">Div three</div>
  <div id="four">Div four</div>
  <div id="five">Div five</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's better not to use fade() function on jquery... instead you can toggle a css class that has animation or whatever like show and hide the element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ali** is right, It's better to work with css `add/removeclasses` instead of `fadeIn/Out`

<strike><sup>For me its not a better but its the only way to do it</sup></strike> <sup>because it can be done with jquery `animation`</sup>

With css you'll need to use `max-height` , `opacity` for fadeIn/Out and `transition` to make the animation

<sup>Note: there're alot of proprties in css can make tons of effects like `animation` , `transform` .. its depending on what you want to do</sup>

Take a look at the next code

```js
$(function(){
  $("#buttons a").on('click', function() {
    var div = '#' + $(this).attr('data-div');
    
    /* For clicked anchor */
    $(this).siblings().not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    
    /* For Showing div */
    $(div).siblings().not(div).removeClass('active');
    $(div).addClass('active');
  })
  /* click on the first one onload */
  .filter("[data-div='one']").click();
});
```

```css
#my-component {
margin-top: 2em;
}

#my-component div {
  opacity : 0;
  max-height : 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* active div */
#my-component div.active {
  max-height : 50vh;
  opacity : 1;
  transition : opacity 1s ease;
}

#buttons a {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 .25em;
  cursor: pointer
}

/* active anchor */
#buttons a.active{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="buttons">
  <a data-div="one">Show One</a>
  <a data-div="two">Show Two</a>
  <a data-div="three">Show Three</a>
  <a data-div="four">Show Four</a>
  <a data-div="five">Show Five</a>
</div>


<div id="my-component">
  <div id="one">Div one</div>
  <div id="two">Div two</div>
  <div id="three">Div three</div>
  <div id="four">Div four</div>
  <div id="five">Div five</div>
</div>
```